# UIWebView delegate 2 viewControllers

Tags: ios, uiwebviewdelegate

I've got 2 viewControllers: WebviewViewController and AnotherViewController. And here is mainWebView on WebviewViewController.
I delegate mainWebView to WebviewController. And this works perfect:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    NSLog(@"Finish upload");
}
```

Then I create UIWebView for AnotherViewController.

```
@interface AnotherViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *Webview;
}
```

Link Webview with webView from WebviewController in interfaceBuilder. And try to use delegate method in AnotherViewController class.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)Webview{
    NSLog(@"NIIIIIICE!");
}
```

Result:

```
2011-10-14 13:54:46.363 TakeInputs[4558:207] Finish upload
```

I understand that it's so stupid but I'm stacked. I want to use delegate methods in two classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to link your AnotherViewController to your webview like below in viewdidload of AnotherViewController

```
webview.delegate = self
```

that's it, now your delegate method should be in 
AnotherViewController.m file